# How to print number and "*" combination in java

Tags: java

My program is as below:

```java
package simplemirror;

public class simple {
    public static void main (String arg[]){
        for( int i = 1; i <= 3; i++ ){

            for( int j = 0; j < i; j++ ){
                System.out.print(i+"*");
            }

            System.out.println("");
        }
    }
}
```

Above program output is as below:

```
1*
2*2*
3*3*3*
```

I need output as below:

```
1
2*2
3*3*3
2*2
1
```

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow, I recommend you review http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: I had to do the same thing in my Java Programming class...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

this code will work try this.............:)

```
public class simple {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        int n;
        n=3;         
        for(int i=1;i<2*n;i++){
            if(i<=n){
                for(int j=1;j<i;j++){
                    System.out.print(i+"*");
                }
                System.out.println(i);
            }
            else{
                for(int j=i+1;j<2*n;j++){
                    System.out.print(2*n-i+"*");
                }
                System.out.println(2*n-i);
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

EDIT: 
It's been a while, and I have learned a few things.

You can use streams!

```
private static void print(int num) {
    IntStream.concat(
            IntStream.iterate(1, (i) -> ++i).limit(num),
            IntStream.iterate(num - 1, (i) -> --i).limit(num).limit(num - 1))
            .boxed()
            .map(i -> Stream.generate(i::toString).limit(i).collect(Collectors.joining("*")))
            .forEach(System.out::println);
}
```

Comment: Sorry JClassic i was got sucked from last two days!!Thank you so much !!

Answer (score 0):

try

```
public static void main(String[] args) {  
    int limit=5;
    int rows=limit+(limit-1);
    int center=(int) Math.ceil(((double)rows/2));
    boolean centerReached=false;
    for(int i=1;i<=limit&&i>0;){
        for(int j=1;j<=i;j++){
            System.out.print(i);
            if(i==j)
                continue;
            System.out.print("*");
        }
        if(center==i)
            centerReached=true;
        if(centerReached)
            i--;
        else
            i++;
        System.out.println();
    }
}
```

ouptut

```
1
2*2
3*3*3
4*4*4*4
5*5*5*5*5
4*4*4*4
3*3*3
2*2
1
```

Answer (score -1):

Please don't ask such question here. Ans to your question may be looks like follows but once again don't ask such questions here.

```
public class simple {
public static void main (String arg[])
{
for( int i = 1; i <= 3; i++ ){
for( int j = 0; j < i; j++ ){
if(j== i-1)
{
System.out.print(i);
}
else
{
System.out.print(i+"*");
}
}
System.out.println("");
}
}
}
```

Comment: Okay then were to ask such question

Comment: try to solve it your self only then you will understand basic concepts of programming